# How to get the `id` of the element just created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

Let's say I have a following code:

```
function createElement(element) {
  $('#container').append(element);
}
createElement('<div id='abc'>Some content</div>');
```

I'd like to let the function know which element `id` it creating (hopefully without parsing of the `element` string) to manipulate with just created element such as setting the position.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function createElement(element) {
   var node = $(element);
   $('#container').append(node);
   alert(node.attr('id'));
}
createElement('<div id="abc">Some content</div>');
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsQFp/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.appendTo()` in this context,

```
function createElement(element) {
   return $(element).appendTo('#container');
}

console.log(createElement('<div id="abc">Some content</div>').attr('id'))
```

Comment: @SridharR - it also works you missed <div id="container"></div> in html part in the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.id to get the id like this:

```
function createElement(element) {
  var id = $(element).attr('id');//and do your stuff with the id
  $('#container').append(element);
}
createElement('<div id="abc">Some content</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

just do:

```
function createElement(element) {
  $('#container').append(element);
    return $(element).attr("id");
}
console.log(createElement('<div id="abc">Some content</div>'));
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5PXt/)